# Fixed size object array in LibGdx

Tags: arrays, object, libgdx

I want to create an object array with fixed size in LibGDX,where I want to add fixed number and type of object.

I used to create object array like this.

```
    private Array<Coin> coins = new Array<Coin>();
    coin = objectFactory.createCoin();//method to create single coin object
    coins.add(coin);
```

But with this type of array,I could add objects dynamically only.
Adding size like this also have no effect.

```
    private Array<Coin> coins = new Array<Coin>(10);
```

How can I define a object array thats size and elements are fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure that you can use a regular array to achieve what you want:

```
private Coin coins[] = new Coin[10]; // size 10
coins[0] = objectFactory.createCoin(); // set element at first position
Coin coin = coins[5]; // get element at position 5 (6th element)
```